# Could I achieve even more optimization to log the exception?

Tags: java, optimization

I am writing this code and PMD complains that

**Name**

private method void xyzMethod(AnyObject anyObject)

**Location**

class XYZClass (xyz.package)

**Problem synopsis**

***An instanceof check is being performed on the caught exception. Create a separate catch clause for this exception type.***

```
    try {
        premium = serviceCallEjb(anfrage);
    } catch (Exception e){
        final int typeError;
        if(e instanceof ServiceException){
            typeError =  CcaLogManager.ERROR;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } else {
            typeError = CcaLogManager.WARN;
        }
        myAnfrage.setStatus(DcAnfrage.ProcessingError);
        myAnfrage.setStatusInfo(e.getMessage());
        final String message = String.format("Error in CcaMotorinsuranseCalculator, caught: %s, message: %s",e.getClass().getName(),e.getMessage());
        CcaLogManager.log(typeError, message);
    }
```

Do you prefer if I write it like this?

Any other optimization I could make?

```
    try {
        premium = serviceCallEjb(anfrage);
    }
    catch(ServiceException e){
        final int typeError;
        typeError =  CcaLogManager.ERROR;
        e.printStackTrace();
        processException(e, typeError);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        final int typeError;
        typeError = CcaLogManager.WARN;            
        processException(e, typeError);
    }

private <T extends Exception> void processException(T e, final int typeError){
    this.myObject.setStatus(/*Any number*/7);
    this.myObject.setStatusInfo(e.getMessage());
    final String message = String.format("Error in Some place, caught: %s, message: %s",e.getClass().getName(),e.getMessage());
    Logger.log(typeError, message);
}
```

Comment: ServiceException is an error, any other exception is a warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, I would recommend against calling `e.printStackTrace()` in any production code. It sends raw output to the standard error stream of the process, which is never useful in an EJB application. In any case, even if you do end up printing to `stderr`, that logic should reside within your exception processing code. When you eliminate that, your code could look like this:

```
try {
    premium = serviceCallEjb(anfrage);
}
catch (Exception e){
    processException(e, e instanceof ServiceException?
                     CcaLogManager.ERROR : CcaLogManager.WARNING);
}
```

Given this form, it seems that even the `instanceof` logic could be a part of `processException`'s job description. That way the one method would capture all he business rules of exception processing in your entire application.

If your only goal is satisfying PMD, then this would be a clean version:

```
try {
    premium = serviceCallEjb(anfrage);
}
catch (ServiceException e){
    processException(e, CcaLogManager.ERROR);
}
catch (Exception e){
    processException(e, CcaLogManager.WARNING);
}
```